# Will Db conneection get closed in following situaltion?

Tags: c#, odbc, database-connection

I have question on connection I create in C# code

To Read data I have written Factory Class for all the read which is as follows

```
Public static OracleDataReader(CommandType ct,string command,params OracleParameter[] cp)
{
    OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(getconnection());
    try
    {
        return ExecuteReader(cn,ct,command,cp);
    }
    catch
    {
        cn.close();
    }
}
```

Now I use it as follows

```
qry = "select * from emp";
using(IDataReader dr = OracleFacoty.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text,qry,null)
{
    while(dr.read())
    {
        //Do operation
    }
}
```

Now my question is, will the connection opened in factory method will be closed automatically or I Need pass the connection from calling method and close the connection once i am done with data read.

Answer (score 0):

The using statement will dispose the dB connection properly when it's instantiated within it checkout this from msdn regarding this approach of like you did

You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case, the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged resources. In other words, it will no longer be fully initialized. If you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an exception to be thrown. For this reason, it is generally better to instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to the using block.

I would suggest probably use using and instantiate connection and pass that instance to your factory methods to perform any operations, by end the using will then properly dispose the database connection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but i am not creating connection in using statement? will still it disponse the connection with Ireader object

Comment: didn't realize you were not instantiating connection within using I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I can say

- You have a static method in class which **Creates new Connection** each time you call it and returns some DataTable object(?)
- Whenever an error occurs within `ExecuteReader()`, exception is suppressed and connection closes without questions.

But in Second snippet, you're not using `OracleDataReader` you're directly calling `ExecuteReader()` which, as I believe, will not handle **any** exceptions.

Also, in first snippet, connection closes only when an error occurs. If no error, connection will not close and will cause memory leaks and after some attempts it max outs connection limits.

If you need new connection for every call, then put the `Cn.close()` in `finally{}` block.